# Does there exist a multigraph with no self-loops which has exactly one vertex of odd degree?

Tags: graph-theory

Does there exist a multigraph with no self-loops which has exactly one vertex of odd degree?

---

*Context*: While I was reviewing the Königsberger problem I wanted to draw a simple example with just one vertex of odd degree to create an example of a multigraph with no eulerian circuit. After not succeeding at drawing it I started to ask myself this question.

Comment: HINT: Count the ends of the edges.

Comment: Showing your own thoughts on the problem is important. Also, providing reference to your course/book/learning media is also important.

Comment: While I was reviewing the Königsberger problem I wanted to draw a simple example with just one vertex of odd degree to create an example of a multigraph with no eulerian circuit. After not succeeding at drawing it I started to ask myself this question.

Comment: Consider the handshaking lemma.

Comment: I tried to do it, but I couldn't get to a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add the degrees you get twice the number of edges as a result. Therefore the sum of the degrees is even, this means the number of vertices with odd degree is even. Hence there cannot be exactly one vertex of odd degree.

Comment: Thank you! That's a very nice and quick proof!